# Crystal Reports 2008-Sage x3

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created 5 Parameters in crystal reports and I have to create the combinations for each one of them so the joins will work.

For example: I have the ones and the twos and the trees and the fours and the fives. But unfortunately the code won't take the 3 parameters inserted. Is there any other syntax or a way that crystal will accept it?

```
IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};





IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};





IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};




IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*' OR 
     {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};





IF {?param1deb} <> '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} <> '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} <> '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} <> '' and {?param5deb} = '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};

IF {?param1deb} = '' and {?param2deb} = '' and {?param3deb} = '' and {?param4deb} = '' and {?param5deb} <> '' then
    ({AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*') AND
     {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
     {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
     {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
(
({?param1deb} <> '' AND {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param1deb}+'*') OR
({?param2deb} <> '' AND {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param2deb}+'*') OR
({?param3deb} <> '' AND {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param3eb}+'*') OR
({?param4deb} <> '' AND {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param4deb}+'*') OR
({?param5deb} <> '' AND {AFCTEXE.FCT_0} LIKE {?param5deb}+'*')
 ) AND
 {AUTILIS.ZITUSR_0} <> 2 and
 {AUTILIS.ENAFLG_0} = 2 and
 {AUTILIS.USR_0} in {?userdeb} to {?userfin};
```